# excel default value for IF

Tags: excel, function, if-statement

Is it possible to add a "default value" for an if?

Let's give an example:

`if (formula="", "", formula)` or more specifically:

`if (trim(INDIRECT(ADDRESS($G$2+1+$K6,$F6+L$5,4,TRUE,$F$2))) = "", "", INDIRECT(ADDRESS($G$2+1+$K6,$F6+L$5,4,TRUE,$F$2)))`

Comment: Why not drop the `IF` completely? The formula gives either `""` or non-`""` and in the first case, you need to get `""` and in the second case, without the `trim` (which I believe will be better with the trim unless you have a good reason not to trim), you want it itself...

Comment: I put If because it the cell that I check is empty the formula givex a zero "0" instead of an empty string (""). Now, I just checked with the trim and it works. Thank you very much. However the question is the same for a different context: if (complex_formula=something,complex_formula,"")

Comment: Unfortunately no. The closest thing you can have is restricted to expressions that give an error and you don't want to get the error. In that case, you can use `IFERROR`. E.g. `IFERROR(formula, 0)` will return the result of the formula, unless it gives an error, in which case it returns `0`.

Answer (score 0):

In the specific case where you want to convert a complex formula that returns zero to an empty string (or some other default), you could use IFERROR and the fact that dividing by zero produces an error

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/complex_formula),"")
```

That only works if you're trying to catch a zero though. Otherwise you're stuck with an IF.

Sometimes you can simplify complex_formula to determine why it returns zero. If you have

```
partial_complex_formula*cell
```

where cell being zero is the most likely case that the whole thing returns zero. Then you can simply test for that rather than running the whole formula. It's a pretty narrow case, though.

Answer (score 0):

I find the best way to deal with this in Excel is to have one cell to hold the root value of interest (in your case, `=trim(INDIRECT(ADDRESS($G$2+1+$K6,$F6+L$5,4,TRUE,$F$2)))`, and another cell to do the logic that substitutes with a default value: `=IF(M6="","", M6)`  Of course the column holding the intermediate calculation can be hidden.